# Is it possible to have a panel on second monitor in Ubuntu Budgie?

Tags: multiple-monitors, panel, dock, budgie

Trying to place a new separate panel (or dock) in my second monitor I found out that this is not possible.

Is there any workaround for that?

Mind you that it't not a big deal as it will mostly be covered by a Blender window in full-screen mode, but it would be nice to place some stuff there and save space in the main panel.

THX ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you can not do that. 
As far as I know, it will [appear in Budgie 11.0](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues/436), so I guess you could wait some time for 11.0 or have a look at [the Budgie 11 development repo](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-rd) and see if you find what you need. (I'd say it's probably not worth it, *and* I assume they haven't even touched that topic in development yet, but you can at least try)
As for a workaround, I didn't find any.

---

The other way would be using a different panel/dock like the preinstalled `plank`